# On hover animation: Icon must get closer to the text, right now it works the other way around

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, css-animations

**What I want:**
On hover I want the link to play one animation were the ">" moves closer to the text.

**What I have:**
The animation works, but the text is the one moving closer to the ">". I know why this happens but I have no idea how to fix it. If the icon was on the right side this should be easy.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#">Lees Meer</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
  color: #0079D3;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a::before {
  content: '\f054';
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 0.65rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

a:hover {
  color: #003082;
}

a:hover::before {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set the icon to be absolutely positioned, add spacing on the link for the icon, then move the icon using the left property.

```css
a {
    color: #0079D3;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: .5rem 1.5rem;
}

a::before {
  content: '\f054';
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 0.65rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

a:hover {
  color: #003082;
}

a:hover::before {
  left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Lees Meer</a>
```